# Android Upload image and phone number to server using OkHttp

Tags: android, image-uploading, okhttp

In my application I have been using `DefaultHttpClient` for uploading images to the server but it takes too much time to give response when server is down. I have put my code here. And AFIK `DefaultHttpClient` is going to be deprecated, so I want to use `OkHttp` instead of `DefaultHttpClient`. So please help me to change my code to use `OkHttp` for uploading images. I have searched a lot but don't know how to make the changes. please help me....

```
public String upLoadImg(byte[] image,String name,String phone,String imei,String randomId){
        String mResponseData = null;
        try{
            mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            mHttpPost = new HttpPost(Constants.BASE_URL +"user/asset");
            mHttpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            mHttpPost.setHeader("mobile-number", phone);
            mHttpPost.setHeader("uid", imei);
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            if(image !=null) {    
                ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(image, name);       
                reqEntity.addPart("file", bab);
            } 

            mHttpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);
            Log.e("TAG", "***** mHttpClient is going to execute ");
            HttpParams httpParameters = mHttpClient.getParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 2 * 1000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 2 * 1000);
            mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpPost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = null;
            if(mHttpResponse!=null)
               resEntity = mHttpResponse.getEntity();
            if(resEntity!=null)
              mResponseData = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();

        }catch(HttpHostConnectException e){
            Log.e("TAG","Exception cannot connect to server while sending images ",e);
            return null;
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("TAG","Exception occured while sending images ",e);
            return null;
        }
        return mResponseData;

    }
```

Comment: Well you yourself should start converting this to OkHttp. Show your results and then ask how it could be done better if it does not work. You can find a lot of examples is you search a bit.

Comment: I would suggest you to use a third party library to save images like `Cloudinary`. Check [this link](http://cloudinary.com/)

Comment: 'it takes too much time to give response when server is down. '. In that case simply set a time out value.

Comment: @greenapps please see my above code i have already set a timeout value of 2 seconds but this is not worked for me, so i have used the following code for setting time out,                                                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
   int timeoutConnection = 3000;  HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
int timeoutSocket = 3000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

Answer (score 0):

I had overcame this issue by replacing DefaultHttpClient with Okhttpclient.
As far as i know DefaultHttpClient is deprecated in latest android versions.So i had switched to OkHttpClient and then all issues fixed